# Python AES Decryption initialization vector & key value- size issue

Tags: encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I am writing Python Decryption logic to decrypt the message (client-side it is encrypted using Java).
Python code:

```
 def decrypt(self, text):        
            decode = base64.b64decode(text)
            cryptor = AES.new(InKey, MODE_CBC, InIV)
            plain_text = cryptor.decrypt(decode)
            return unpad(plain_text)
```

I have received below key & IV values (sample values) from the client team:

> InKey =
> "6asd6587daIs8g2qvi3rJbM9sdasd6cb2kdYC0TOy5zEgTo+8LrQn0UJZAmJCtmX......"(it
> is length of 684 chars) InIV =
> "7as76cascsagoKtID7z1nUakJqzj+Dwl9cL9Q2/zBFbs0Sg3Kw6US8yvvzbkyg2bnjGHWofIWrhMQ/Bcde...."
> (it is length of 684 chars)

Question: While running the above python code, getting the below error. How to convert the above IV value into 16bytes in size and also key-value length?

> *ValueError: Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)*

existing Decryption Java Client follows Hybrid pattern(first using  RSA private key to pull two params(IV & Key)...and then AES cipher to decrypt actual message):

Pseudo code:

```
................................
//Step-1) Generate RSA-PrivateKey
................................
RSAPrivateKey serverPrivateKey = KeyUtils.getPrivateKey("lib", PrivKey); 
/* here PrivKey refers to .der certificate 
   and FYI- KeyUtils actually refers to a class, that generate RSA PrivateKey with below code:      
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                KeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
            return (RSAPrivateKey)keyFactory.generatePrivate(ks);
*/
................................
//Step-2) use RSA-PrivateKey to decrypt the message
................................
MessageEncryption encryptor = new MessageEncryption(serverPrivateKey); 
/* initializes Cipher(RSA instance) with passed RSA PrivateKey 
 this.m_asymmetricalKey = serverPrivateKey;
 this.m_asymmetricalCipher = Cipher.getInstance(this.m_asymmetricalKey.getAlgorithm());
*/

encryptor.decryptMessage(JSONresponseBody);  // invokes below mentioned method
...............
decryptMessage(JSONObject jsonMessage)
{
    .............................
    IvParameterSpec initializationVector = new IvParameterSpec(this.m_asymmetricalCipher.doFinal(StringCodec.decodeBase64(jsonMessage.getString("iv").getBytes())));     
    this.m_asymmetricalCipher.init(2, this.m_asymmetricalKey);          
    Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(this.m_asymmetricalCipher.doFinal(StringCodec.decodeBase64(jsonMessage.getString("key").getBytes())), "AES");
    Cipher symmetricalCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    symmetricalCipher.init(2, secretKey, initializationVector);
    return new String(symmetricalCipher.doFinal(StringCodec.decodeBase64(jsonMessage.getString("message").getBytes())));
    .............................   

}
..............
```

So at Python how to get right key-size & IV, is there way to implement similar hybrid pattern at java or does it any other approach to deal with at python ?

Thanks.

Comment: Those values are base64 encoded, and there is no sensible way to get 16 or 32 bytes from 686 characters of base64-encoded bytes. Perhaps these are the result of RSA encryption with a 4096-bit RSA modulus, but even then I would expect 684 characters, not 686. Also there's no reason to encrypt the IV. You will have to find out more details from your "client team", there's really no such thing as a Java *generic* encryption sample.

Comment: Thanks James for responding. Yes you are right it was 684 chars that resulted from RSA Encryption with 4096 bit Modulus. Now we are looking to find a way to get the expected 16-bytes size of IV & Key from base64 encoded 684 chars.

Comment: It would help if we could see the encryption code.

Comment: Thanks @bereal for looking into this. Yes now i updated more details at the post. Could you pls help to check and let me know, if you can provide any inputs here. FYI- we don't have encryption code, its all we deal the decryption logic.

Comment: @bereal could you pls let us know, if you have got any inputs on the solution for this issue posted.

Comment: @AshokBottu some details are still missing, at least, to decrypt it you'll need the RSA private key.

Comment: Thanks @bereal, yes we have RSA private Key with us. Kindly pls let me know, what details the post missing, so that I can sure add at post. At this moment at python code we stuck to derive the right Key & IV (16 bytes size) from base64 encoded string. Where as in Java we see it easily got using  IvParameterSpec  and  SecretKeySpec  methods(by passing RSAPrivate Key & encoded base64 string)- shown at posted java code. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java-side code does the following things:

1. Read the PKCS8-encoded RSA key
2. Decode the base64-encoded IV
3. Decrypt the IV using the private key (a side-note: encrypting IV makes very little sense to me)
4. Decode the base64-encoded AES key
5. Decrypt the AES key using the private key
6. Decode the base64-encoded cyphertext
7. Decrypt the ciphertext using the obtained IV and AES key

You need to re-implement each of the above steps in Python. Some are trivial, like base64-decoding. The others depend on the cryptography libraries you're using.